# How can I get all of the django foreignkey objects in one shot?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Context: `Foo` is a class that has a foreignKey field pointing to a `Bar` object. Several `Foo`s may refer to the same `Bar`. (Many to one)

I need to reference several fields of a `Foo` object's foreignkey (`Bar.field` and `Bar.field2`), but it seems that each time I do so it runs a separate query.

As a result, referencing these fields can take forever.

Is there a way to get *all* the `Bar` objects in a single query? Or is there a better way to speed it up?

```
foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(params) # takes 0.001 sec, returns 10k objects

result = []

for f in foo_list:

    # this part takes 40 seconds due to the huge number of queries 
    bar = f.bar # Foo contains a foreignKey reference to the Bar class

    result.append({
        "field": f.field,
        "barField": bar.barField,
        "barField2": bar.barField2,

        # this way was even worse
        # "barField": f.bar.barField,
        # "barField2": f.bar.barField2, 
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(params).select_related()
```

does the job. The rest of the code would remain the same, but

```
for f in foo_list:
    f.bar
```

would use the cached objects

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `select_related` method on your queryset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), which will do the joins for you in the initial query.  So in your case, something like:

```
foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(params).select_related()
```

If you have a very deep chain of linked models, it may be worth also limiting the depth so that you only get the bar objects (and not any additional links beyond that like `.select_related(depth=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) look up's eg:

```
foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(params).values('field','bar__barField','bar__barField2')
```

This will do the job in one query and the result set will have the required fields as well.